# How to open a new spreadsheet from an existing spreadsheet using a button (on Client Side)?

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, openurl

I am trying to make a button in a Google spreadsheet which points to another spreadsheet. The `Spreadsheet.OpenbyUrl()` opens the spreadsheet on the Server side and not the client side.

```
Can anyone Help??

function open()
{  
 SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxx');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a button, you can only call a server function. And server functions can not open a tab or window in your browser.

That's a no go.

But you can have a button (or a menu item) that will open a dialog box with a link in it. That link will open the URL (because it's a client's code).

So it will be a two steps action.

### Code:

```
function showLink(){
  var html = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r-y7vidMXbPrxsg_tgL22eZcUqLNIBonJFB6k_iQb9c'; target='_blank'>Open this url</a>";
  var anchor = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(60).setWidth(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(anchor,"Click this link")
}
```

You can also close it automatically:

```
  var html = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r-y7vidMXbPrxsg_tgL22eZcUqLNIBonJFB6k_iQb9c'; target='_blank'  onclick='google.script.host.close()' />Open this url</a>";
```