# Open a different spreadsheet in the client browser from a custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to open google sheets from a custom (bound) menu in another sheet. The scripts "run" but do not open the sheets I am trying to open (by "open, I mean, they are not visible in a new browser tab).

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
    .addItem('Open Create', 'openCreate')
    .addItem('Open Perform', 'openPerform')
    .addItem('Open Catalog', 'openCatalog')
    .addToUi();
}
function openCreate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("create ID goes here");
}
function openPerform() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("perform ID goes here");
}
function openCatalog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("catalog ID goes here");
}
```

What am I missing (doing wrong)?

Comment: `openById` returns an object representing your spreadsheet it not opening it in a new tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210489/how-to-open-a-new-spreadsheet-from-an-existing-spreadsheet-using-a-button-on-cl)

Comment: I realize that I am declaring ss as a variable and then not using it. I assume I need to use to actually open a tab with spreadsheet, but have tried a bunch of possibilities like "return", but nothing working so far.

Comment: Casper's right. His linked solution working. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new spreadsheet from an existing spreadsheet using a button (on Client Side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210489/how-to-open-a-new-spreadsheet-from-an-existing-spreadsheet-using-a-button-on-cl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guided by Casper's suggested link, here's what worked.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Website', 'openSite')
      .addToUi();
}
function openSite() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = "<a href='url'; target='_blank'>Open Site</a>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Google Site');
  }
```